# How to make sortable work with multi divs with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

How to make this sortable work for multi divs with the same class name #sortable.

here is an example

> **update**

```
      <div class="multi-fields" id="sortable">
          //something
      </div>

      <div class="multi-fields" id="sortable">
          //another something
      </div>
```

sortable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        cursor:'move',
        opacity: 0.5,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        axis: 'y',
        update:function(event, ui){
    var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
        data: "action=update_field_order&" + order
        });
    }});
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$("#sortable")` will select all tags with id equals to "sortable", NOT classes.
2. Check your console. Do you get any errors regarding `.sortable`?
3. Class name '#sortable' is NOT valid. Change it to "sortable" and change the selector to `$(".sortable")` . Does it work now?

EDIT
To be exact, (3) IS valid in HTML5. Still a better practice is to start your class / id names with a letter. In case you have to go with '#' you will have to escape it in the jQ selector. This is unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnPan, Kindly can you give me an answer within my code so I can understand, I'm still learning.

Comment: id stands for Identification. It is semantically absolutely wrong for two elements to have the same id. So in your HTML change 'id' to 'class', and in the selector go with ".sortable". Press F12 and check if there are any errors too

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be saying this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
      $(".sortable").sortable({
      cursor:'move',
      opacity: 0.5,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      axis: 'y',
      update:function(event, ui){
       var order = $('.sortable').sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
        data: "action=update_field_order&" + order
      });
      }});
      $(".sortable").disableSelection();
      });
      </script>
```

Change also the id attribute to class and try!

Comment: Thank you, Yeah I did as @JohnPan mentioned with the same solution.

Comment: Was typing the answer when he responded!